# Android - How to change Activities within a TabActivity?

Tags: android, android-activity, viewflipper, android-tabactivity

I currently have a TabActivity which has 4 tabs, within one of the tab's I want to be able to move forward and back between 4 different Activities.

However if I try to start a new Activity now it removes the TabActivty and starts a whole new Activity with no tab bars.

I have read about using view groups but that this is not best practice and also about using a view flipper but this doesn't seem to let me switch between different Activities only change the views within the Activity. I can't implement back functionality for exa,ple.

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to what I should be looking for as a solution to this?

EDIT:

Some more information:

Within the TabActivity my first screen will be a ListView that contains 4 rows, then selecting one of these will in turn load another ListView with 2 rows again within the TabActivity and then the 3rd screen will just contain some text depending on which option the user chose again within the Tab Activity.

Is a ViewFlipper the best solution here? It seems to me that it will require a lot of coding within one Activity if I use the ViewFlipper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done something similar. I used the ViewFlipper to achieve this. You can override `onBackPressed` in your Activity so you can deal with moving back through your views.

There's a couple of ways of doing this but a simple way would be to just increment a counter in your Activity as you move to the next views, then in your `onBackPressed` method if `counter != 0` just show the previous view, if `counter == 0` call `super.onBackPressed`.

You can see in [my video showing what the result could look like](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2nKhgpq3rQA)  (ignore the bug being shown in the video).

Comment: How do I use Viewflipper to switch between activities though?

Comment: Very simple example that will get you started http://android-pro.blogspot.com/2010/09/using-view-flipper-in-android.html

Comment: So I'm guessing that I replace the Textviews inside the flipper view there with my own full views? And then I have to use the one Activity to control those views?